# Django Need help no such table: network_profile

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on a Django Project and having the error as in operational error as no such table network_profile. I have tried everything run syncdb and make migrations and run migrate and so on but I am still having this error is there anyway someone can help me.
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebsRn.png) 
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPAT5.png)

Let me know if you want any information below. Thank You!

Comment: Share some code and context too this much is not enough for solving your problem. Also this type of error mainly comes when you have forgot to make migrations. Are you sure that migrate is working successfully.

Comment: Yea I did both, manage.py makemigrations and migrate. With the name as well.

Comment: Can you share the model code and also the output of migrate.

Comment: I just made a new table it is ok now.